# unexpected token error on simple jQuery onclick to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I am constantly getting the below error while implementing my tiny, simple jQuery onclick to URL button script...

**error:**

```
(index):658 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Simple code I have tried:

```
$('a.button.wc-backward').click(function(){
  window.location = www.website.com;
});
```

with / and without `http:`

```
$('a.button.wc-backward').click(function(){
  window.location = http://www.website.com;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put URL in string quotations:

```
$('a.button.wc-backward').click(function(){
  window.location = "http://www.example.com/page/";
});
```

Comment: Derrr.. Thanks bro.